# How to update already opened navigation drawer?

Tags: android, performance, navigation-drawer, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I've googled this topic all across the internet and havent found solution.

I'm using navigation drawer as a "inbox" where user can see his chat history. NotifyDataSetChanged works fine with "onDrawerOpened" handler, but i would like to update ND even when its in open state.

I tried to:
invalidate listiew, 
invalidate DrawerLayout, 
clearing and adding collection to adapter ofcourse i called notifydatasetchanged

Is there any option to update ND outside onDrawerOpen,Close,Slide etc methods?

Here is my code onCreate method :

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
    DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(MainNavActivity.this);
    listMsg=db.getLastMsg();
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    adapter=new NavDrawerListAdapter(this,listMsg);
    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(MainNavActivity.this);
            listMsg.clear();
            listMsg.addAll(db.getLastMsg());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

My adapter:

```
    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> msg) {
        super(context, 0, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Message msg=getItem(position);
        Log.v("onReceieve","getView");
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_item, null);
            holder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            holder.msg=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMsg);
            holder.time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

            holder.msg.setText(msg.getText());
            holder.time.setText(msg.getTime());
            holder.name.setText(msg.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And here i receive new message and try to update ND

```
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("onReceive","Poklican");

        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(MainNavActivity.this);
        listMsg.clear();
        listMsg.addAll(db.getLastMsg());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You notfied the adapter for the data change. However, it does not automatically update the display. Use .notifyDataAetChanged() on the host of the data you are changing.

Comment: You mean listview adapter? I am doing that with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), this code works in onOpen() method, but not inside my receiver..